# How to store faces locally?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

this question is in regard to Microsoft's Cognitive Services Face API.

So there's a Face Storage function in the API that allows for storing faces on Azure and later identification, similarity matching, but it seems that this data is stored on Azure.

I wanted to know if it's possible to store this face data locally and use the API for matching/scoring with a new image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have this feature yet. Because the only thing we get is a face-id. So we don't really know what kind of information they keep related to the faces (unlike AWS which states that it extracts some features from the face and save it as a field in a database. However it cannot be stored locally as well). Using a facelist/largefacelist you can store it on the Azure servers indefinitely, but of course it will cost you.

Even if you save this data locally somehow, there is no way to send a feature list of the face to the identification API anyway, so storing locally won't be useful.

Comment: Hey radalin,
Thanks for the response.
Do you know  any more APIs that allow for such capabilities with local/offline storage and verification?

Comment: I guess you can try OpenCV: https://opencv.org Not really an API but something you can install locally and make it work. You need to work on this more though.

Comment: I've been using the Face API and have been using the Person Groups and Verification. You cannot store the images themselves as far as I can see but you can use your own storage option and associate with the faceid, persistedFaceId. I am currently using an azure blob storage to do this so that I can just goto that and retrieve the images when I need to show them

Comment: FaceIDs only lasts for 24 hours (if no recent changes did this). Therefore you can only store them for 24 hours and then you have re-run detections. It's different int Facelists but then those persistedFaceIds cannot be used with person groups